# Обновление div с картой

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api, карты, css

У меня на странице имеется блок с картой из гугла и два адреса. Я хотел бы реализовать смену места на карте по клику на адрес.
Есть идея реализовать простую подмену блоков через Display: none, но почему-то не сработало. Блок выходит без содержимого. А при попытке возврата к первому первый тоже отказывается работать.

---

Пример хороший и работает, но при попытке его реализовать ничего не выдавало.
Ключ АПИ я подставил.
Ошибка при подставке переменных, так как если в строку для начального вывода подставить значение из переменной то все выводится.
При попытке сменить расположение карты из консоли выдает, что переменная Map не определена.

Comment: @Wolf Light, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Стало интересно, решил реализовать, вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/j4gpgd8e/).

Не забудьте подключить в проект библиотеку гугла: `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js`

`Jquery` по желанию, можно обойтись и без него, если в проекте не используется (в примере он используется для селекторов и функции клика).