# Как переместить пользователя на найденный объект на карте?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google-maps-api-2

Как переместить пользователя на найденный объект на карте Google?

Comment: Телепортация? ;)  
@Oleg Ponomarchuk, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/366472/) есть вариант решения с телепортацией по клику :)